# Realizar una acción en php cuando ejecuta un Delete (MySQL)

Tags: php, html, mysql

Ejecuto un script de Php por medio de un botón, es el siguiente

```
function eliminarDir($carpeta)
     {
      foreach (glob($carpeta . "/*") as $archivos_carpeta)
      {
            if (is_dir($archivos_carpeta))
            {
                eliminarDir($archivos_carpeta);
            }
            else
            {
                unlink($archivos_carpeta);
            }      
        }
        rmdir($carpeta);
    }
    if(isset($_GET['delete_id']))
        {
            $update="UPDATE mensajes SET status_remite = 'eliminado' WHERE id_mensaje=".$_GET['delete_id'];
            mysqli_query($con,$update);
            header("Location: $_SERVER[PHP_SELF]");

            $delete="DELETE from mensajes WHERE status_remite = 'eliminado' and status_destino='oculto' and id_mensaje=".$_GET['delete_id'];



            if (mysqli_affected_rows($con,$delete) > 0){

                $id_mensaje=$_GET['delete_id'];
                eliminarDir('../../files/mensajes/'.$id_mensaje);
                header("Location: $_SERVER[PHP_SELF]");
            }

        }
```

Las dos consultas están funcionando bien, el tema ahora es que el if mysqli_affected_rows no está entrando

Comment: comprueba que efectivamente no esté entrando en el if haciendo un echo o un die, y si sí está entrando entonces pon tu función `elimiarDir`

Comment: Ya lo comprobé con un echo y no esta entrando

Comment: pusiste el die después del echo? dado que tienes una redirección a tu misma página si no pones el díe después del echo no lo vas a ver, o quita el header momentaneamente

Comment: Al parecer no entra al if, quité el header y probé con die también

Comment: Intente validarlo con un `mysql_affected_rows()` dependiendo el conector que este usando, esto devolverá el numero de filas afectadas

Comment: Puedo preguntar por qué haces primero el `update` y después el `delete`, dentro del `if` del `delete`?

Comment: Es por mis status de acuerdo a las condicionales, cuando encuentra ciertas condiciones actualiza o elimina según sea el caso

Comment: ¿Cómo podría incluir mysql_affected_rows() en mi if?

Comment: No se que conector esta usando la validación seria así if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0). consulte la documentación de php correspondiente http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-affected-rows.php

Comment: sería posible que quitaras el segmento de código del `update`, solo como prueba y escribir si lo ejecuta

Comment: Esa es una prueba que ya realice, pero no me esta eliminando el directorio, solo el registro en la tabla

Comment: Tu conexion a la base de datos la haces con un require?, si es asi haz tratado de pasarle la variable `$con` a la funcion `function eliminarDir($carpeta, $con)`

Comment: if (mysqli_affected_rows($con,$delete) > 0){
   
   $id_mensaje=$_GET['delete_id_definitivo'];
    eliminarDir('../../files/mensajes/'.$id_mensaje);
    header("Location: $_SERVER[PHP_SELF]");
  }

Comment: Si no funciona nada de esto intente consultar los log del servidor para ver que muestra en la ejecución de su programa

Comment: tu función abarca todo el código que presentas??, haz intentado poner un `} else {` antes de tu `$delete`

Comment: se ejecuta tu query $delete?? por lo que se ve el  header("Location: $_SERVER[PHP_SELF]"); después del $update impide que se ejecute el resto del código, además te falta un mysqli_query($con,$delete); y después consultar si el mysqli_affected_rows($con) es > 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te sugiero que hagas lo siguiente: comenta el header que redirecciona después de ejecutar la query $update **ya que evita que se ejecute el resto del código**, luego **agrega la ejecución de la query $delete** y finalmente **agrega la redirección más abajo para que se redirija al actualizar y además si elimina o no el dir**, el código quedaría así:

```php
if(isset($_GET['delete_id'])) {
        $update="UPDATE mensajes SET status_remite = 'eliminado' WHERE id_mensaje=".$_GET['delete_id'];
        mysqli_query($con,$update);
        // elimina esta redireccion (se hará mas abajo)
        // header("Location: $_SERVER[PHP_SELF]");

        $delete="DELETE from mensajes WHERE status_remite = 'eliminado' and status_destino='oculto' and id_mensaje=".$_GET['delete_id'];

        // agrega esta linea para ejecutar la query
        mysqli_query($con, $delete);

        // actualiza esta condicional
        if (mysqli_affected_rows($con) > 0){

            $id_mensaje=$_GET['delete_id'];
            eliminarDir('../../files/mensajes/'.$id_mensaje);

            // elimina esta redireccion (se hará mas abajo)
            // header("Location: $_SERVER[PHP_SELF]");
        }

        // aca agrega la redireccion
        header("Location: $_SERVER[PHP_SELF]");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

podrías agregar esto para poder saber que devuelve.

```
mysqli_query($con, $delete);
printf("Records deleted: %d\n", mysql_affected_rows());

    if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0) {
        echo "se elimino";
    } else {
        echo $delete;
        echo "Error al eliminar: " . mysqli_error($con);
    }
```

verifica que tu query sea correcta

Comment: No ocurre nada, al parecer no está entrando al if

Comment: haber .. primero captura la query del delete y verifica q este correcta .. --> echo $delete; .. ponlo antes del mysqli_query,, si es correcta te diría que borres todo respecto al update ( incluye el header) y vuelvas a intentar .. así descartamos el posible error.

Comment: Ya probé sin el update, imprimí $delete pero no me imprime nada, sin embargo sí me borra el registro, si pongo el if no entra tampoco ya que no borra el directorio y si pongo una alerta  dentro tampoco se ejecuta

Comment: eso si es esta raro . que el $delete no te imprima nada. posiblemente el and id_mensaje=".$_GET['delete_id']  este dando error .. podrías intentar con and id_mensaje=1 "    y ver si pinta algo.  y cuando dices que si borrar el registro .. eso quiere decir que la query es correcta .. pero no lo borra cuando esta en el if.

Comment: es raro porque no me imprime nada, y si imprimo update si me captura la query :/

Comment: y si por casualidad le cambias el nombre de variable .. $delete.... pone $sql

Comment: Estaba olvidando colocar mi función, ya entra ahora el tema es que me borra siempre mi directorio, ¿cómo puedo poner un if cuando fue afectada la columnas con el delete ?

Comment: aja .. si ya entro , pues solo debes de validar si ese delete afecto .. agrega esta linea justo despues de ejecutar el delete .. 
mysqli_query($con,$delete);

printf("Records deleted: %d\n", mysql_affected_rows()); eso te devolvera un entero.. 0 si es que borro algo caso contrario se ejecuto correctamente.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84880/discussion-between-indirarivas-and-gerard-caceres).

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esto `if($delete > 0) { #acción a realizar }` con esto entrara al `if` si la consulta se ejecuto correctamente.

---

Ahora para eliminar un archivo o directorio.

Elimina el directorio en php es con `unlink(#ruta del fichero a eliminar)`, asegúrate que la ruta es la correcta así como el nombre del archivo.

Comment: Gracias a tu comentario me di cuenta que no había incluido mi función eliminarDir, ahora el tema es que me elimina din haberse afectado algun fila, cómo puedo incluir eso en mi if

Comment: comprueba que el UPDATE se este ejecutando antes que el DELETE ya que si tu update no se ejecuta no cambiara el status_remite a "eliminado" y el delete no se ejecutara.

Comment: agrega esta condición if ($update){ 'Aquí va el código del delete' } con esto si el update no se ejecuta  tampoco eliminara el fichero ni se lanzara el delete sobre la BD.